# tracking loaded classes out of .EAR/.WAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, build, websphere, war, ear

In WAS-8.0/8.5, how can I confirm that all .jars/classes are loaded by the server ?

Issue is this, that, I am getting NoClassDefFoundError in WAS-8.5, for a class which is already deployed but unable to load at runtime.

Comment: If you want to see classes loaded, you can use WAS admin console to see it: Troubleshooting->Class loader viewer->pick your app->pick WAR/EJB jar. Note: you must enable class loader viewer service. Also, please show stack trace and EAR structure with info where is this class located (in utility JAR/WAR/EJB JAR).

Comment: In WAS-8.5, Troubleshooting->Class loader viewer option is not available. It has- Diagnostic trace service/Logging and tracing 
/Change log detail levels/NCSA access and HTTP error logging 
. I have enabled "Additional Properties ->Class loader viewer service.

Comment: Following is the .EAR structure- DummyPortal.EAR/lib,DummyPortal.EAR/lib/Counter.jar, DummyPortal/DummyWar.WAR, DummyPortal/DummyWar/MyJsp.jsp. In "MyJsp.jsp", I am accessing a class from "Counter.jar" and there I am getting "NoClassDefFoundError" exception. Not sure, why it's not referring "Counter.jar". Would it be a bug in WAS-8.5 ?

Comment: I guess your WAR does not see class from JAR because it is missing an entry in Deployment Assembly. WAS reads this from WAR MANIFEST.MF file (it is located inside META-INF directory). Did you configure EAR lib directory to be lib (right click on EAR->Properties->Deployment Assembly)? If yes, then you must add Counter.jar into WAR Deployment Assembly (righ click on DummyWar WAR project->Properties->Deployment Assembly->tab Manifest entries->Add).

Comment: Ok, Magic Wand I will try this and update soon, Cheers

Comment: So, I followed your suggestions and now .JSP is able to refer "AlphabetCounter.class" from "Counter.jar". But now, "AlphabetCounter" is not able to find Class: "CounterConstants", which as well present in "Counter.jar". It seems "AlphabetCounter" is not looking in "Counter.jar", for "CounterConstants". Do I need to add following entry in the manifest file of "Counter.jar" ? Manifest-Entry: Class-Path: "." ?

Comment: Following is the short stack trace:                                           Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0320E: The [MyFilter] filter was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred.
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: DispatcherServlet
Error Stack: 
com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: Unable to obtain an instance for @Inject java.lang.reflect.Field.cm: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mycompany.constants.CounterConstants (initialization failure)

Comment: Thank you Magic Wand for providing me informative help. The problem is solved after creating  fresh .EAR & .WAR projects. The only change I did was choose .EAR-Version-7.0 instead of .EAR-Version-6.0(which I had choosen earlier). I am using STS-3.5.1. and now I am building analogy that when we export.EAR-6.0 build then it shall create issues on WAS-8.5. Moreover, .EAR-7.0 exported build doesn't need any "Class-Path manisfest-entry.; it by default looks into .EAR/lib/jars for the dependent classes.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- put counter.jar file to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your `war` if it is module specific,
- put counter.jar to the `lib` folder of the `ear`, if is shared by many modules
- add it to `MANIFEST.MF` file, either in the way [Magic Wand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3839840/magic-wand) described or if you dont have Eclipse, just add following to the file:

> Class-path: counter.jar

Comment: Thank you Gas for the response.So, I followed "Magic Wand" suggestions and now .JSP is able to refer "AlphabetCounter.class" from "Counter.jar". But now, "AlphabetCounter" is not able to find Class: "CounterConstants", which as well present in "Counter.jar". It seems "AlphabetCounter" is not looking in "Counter.jar", for "CounterConstants". Do I need to add following entry in the manifest file of "Counter.jar" ? Manifest-Entry: Class-Path: "." ?

Comment: Also, "lib" folder of my DummyPortal.EAR has "Counter.jar".Because it is suppose to be accessed by more than 1 .WAR modules.

Comment: Following is the short stack trace:                                           Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0320E: The [MyFilter] filter was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred.
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: DispatcherServlet
Error Stack: 
com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: Unable to obtain an instance for @Inject java.lang.reflect.Field.cm: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mycompany.constants.CounterConstants (initialization failure)

Comment: @G.S.Tomar If your CounterConstants is in the jar, and you are trying to inject it, you should have beans.xml in META-INF folder in that jar.

Comment: beans.xml is already present in META-INF of "Counter.jar". CDI is working fine. "AlphabetCounter" is the @Inject item and referred by CDI perfectly. Problem starts when the default constructor of "AlphabetCounter" tries to use static constants through "CounterConstants.java".

Comment: @G.S.Tomar Maybe add AlphabetCounter and CounterConstants to your question, and describe which class is where (web module, jar, etc). Is CounterConstants an interface? then you cannot inject it. If it has static constants you just call them CounterConstants.CONSTANT without injection.

Comment: Thank you Gas for providing me informative help( about beans.xml). The problem is solved after creating  fresh .EAR & .WAR projects. The only change I did was choose .EAR-Version-7.0 instead of .EAR-Version-6.0(which I had choosen earlier). I am using STS-3.5.1. and now I am building analogy that when we export.EAR-6.0 build then it shall create issues on WAS-8.5. Moreover, .EAR-7.0 exported build doesn't need any "Class-Path manisfest-entry.; it by default looks into .EAR/lib/jars for the dependent classes.